# Deployed Web app with JEE and can i use its services for Android app?

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee, web-deployment

My idea is if i create web application and deploy it on server will i be able to use its services if also create mobile applications?

And is Java EE better for Web app than php? I know its more expensive because of rent of the server but is it better?

Using:

- JEE
- Restfull services
- MySQl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear @Plamen as to which language to use (Java or Php) it will be your choice. But if you want to create a restful web-service i recommend using Java EE with Jersey(JAX-RS). And also if you want to use your service on android application you can easily use it via Jersey client.

I recommend reading more on http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Just create a rest api in your web project and then you can access it via your android app.

Answer (score 0):

JEE offer better application architecture and organisation along with easier way of integration with others systems so it's mains advantages are maintainability , re-usability and interoperability , So if you expect your code to grow to a certain big number of code line and expect to reuse code in other project than it's a good choice else make it simple use PHP.

Comment: Yes i understand you. Thanks! Probably i will use Java : )

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you can make requests from your mobile app to the Server endpoints. Creating RESTful web services and sending/receiving JSON data is a good and simple way to it.
2. About Java EE or PHP it depends on the application needs. Personally I'd use Java.